# how to get mysql end of lines inside javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

mysql table - text column - has this content

```
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
```

I fetch this content as php `story` variable - and need now to create a `javascript` variable

```
var story = "<?php echo $story; ?>";
```

console says:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

if I change table content to `lorem ipsum lorem ipsum` - it works fine

so obvioysly the problem is with mysql new line characters

I tried - `$story = str_replace(PHP_EOL, "\n", $story);` - before echoing in javascript - but the same result

how to solve this ?

Comment: Use backticks for multiline strings in JS. [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Or use template literals https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals